# delete duplicates and retain MAX(id) mysql

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a code where it list all the duplicates of the data on database

```
SELECT MAX(id) id 
FROM el_student_class_relation 
GROUP BY student_id, class_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now, I'm trying to retain the MAX(id), then the rest of the duplicates should be deleted

I tried the code

```
DELETE us 
FROM el_student_class_relation us
INNER JOIN(SELECT MAX(id) id 
            FROM el_student_class_relation 
            GROUP BY student_id, class_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t ON t.id = us.id
```

But it deletes the MAX(ID) and it is retaining the the other duplicates and it is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: `t.id != us.id` This is what u might need

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?  The second query won't even run in most versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Try this

```
DELETE FROM el_student_class_relation 
WHERE id not in 
( 
        SELECT * from 
            (SELECT MAX(id) id 
            FROM el_student_class_relation 
            GROUP BY student_id, class_id) temp_tbl
)
```

**Please note**: 
do not use the **HAVING COUNT(*) > 1** in inner query.
it will create issue when there is only single record with same id.

Comment: syntax error near 'us where us.id not in ' im using maria db

Answer (score 2):

You might try the following query that deletes all elements for which another one with a higher ID (and same class and student) exists:

```
DELETE
FROM   el_student_class_relation el1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT el2.id
               FROM   el_student_class_relation el2
               WHERE  el1.student_id = el2.student_id
                 AND  el1.class_id = el2.class_id
                 AND  el2.id > el1.id);
```

Comment: MySQL won't let you do a self join on the table being deleted from, even in an  `EXISTS`

Comment: @MatBailie: Didn't know that. I'm more familiar with Oracle. Keep on learning every day....

Comment: OP confirmed MariaDB rather than MySQL.  Self joins are fine in MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

The direct fix for your query is to use an "anti-join", where NOT joining is the important feature. This can be done with `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE
  us 
FROM
  el_student_class_relation us
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT student_id, class_id, MAX(id) id 
    FROM el_student_class_relation 
GROUP BY student_id, class_id
-- HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  [Don't do this, you need to return ALL the rows you want to keep]
)
  gr
    ON gr.id = us.id
WHERE
  gr.id IS NULL  -- WHERE there wasn't a match in the "good rows" table
```

***EDIT*** MariaDB and MySQL aren't the same thing.  MariaDB DOES allow self joins on the table being deleted from.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql(lower version) in case of delete sub-query work a little bit different way, you have to use a layer more than required

```
DELETE FROM el_student_class_relation us
WHERE us.id not in 
( 
   select * from (
            SELECT MAX(id) id 
            FROM el_student_class_relation 
            GROUP BY student_id, class_id 
            ) t1
)
```

Comment: @MatBailie agreed change my query